# How to use SQL Server Profiler in SQL Server with your ASP.NET application?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I want to use a SQL Profiler for stored procedure, can anybody tell me how to do that.
I am runnning a ASP.NET application and i have applied breakpoints on connections open to database to fetch data and proceeding with F11, how can i go to the SQL profiler, and i also dont know how to configure the profiler.

for example:

```
*breakpoint     SQLConnection con;
                con.open();
                SQLCommand cmd = new SQLCommand("SP_MyStoredProcedure",con)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                ..... and some further code....
```

Now how can i jump into the stored procedure with the breakpoint in it from here,on its respective call.

Comment: [sp_ prefix still a no-no](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix) do not use `sp_` prefix for your stored procedure as they are default prefix for System Stored procedures

Comment: thanks, i will make it sure next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kindly follow these steps:

1. Open SQL profiler
2. Provide the correct credentials to connect to your SQL instance
3. You will end up with a screen like the following:
   [image]

up to this moment, it's the same for any trace type that you need to do with the SQL Profiler, the following are the specifics which you may play with according to your scenario

1- TraceName: Give your session a proper name

2- Use the Template: if you wanna find what is taking a long time while being executed, you better stick with the "Standard" template as you are mostly going to monitor the results in an Adhoc way (stepping inside your VS code, and monitoring the results from the profiler screen), other templates are useful but in a different situations (like when you need to have a workload file for the SQL Server Tuning Advisor)

3- Save to (file - Table): select any of them if you wanna save the results for a later use

4- Enable trace stop time: I guess you will not need to specify that option for your proposed scenario

5- Click on "Run" and you will end up with a screen that will capture anything that will be executed in your SQL server, similar to the following screen.
[image]

Notes:

1- You need to care more about the highlighted columns and watch for rows like "Batch completed" or "RPC Completed"

2- If you have more than one active DB on this server and you want to show only those actions which are being executed just inside your desired Database, follow the following steps before you click on "Run" to start the profiler session

a. Click on "Events Selection", then follow the steps shown in the screen below, and in step "4" enter your desired DB name.
[image]

b. click "Ok", then click "Run", and the profiler will only display transaction for your specified Database.

Comment: how to check the queries being run  beside, during the execution of ASP.NET application??? tell me that also please!

Comment: you will simple keep the profiler window open while your app is running, and all the queries from your application to your Db server will show up like the screenshot in my answer.